# java apns getting list of device tokens registered under an application

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the Java APN service to send a push notification messages to all devices registered under an application. It is possible by giving the devices tokens in a static array. I can send that to the devices.

But my question is: Is there any way to get the list of all device tokens registered under an application in a sandbox testing environment or in real production environment?

Answer (score 0):

APNS does not provide a way to query active push tokens.  Most frameworks or services(EasyAPNS, Urban Airship, etc) stores the active push tokens locally (like in a database) and leverages the Feedback Service to remove inactive tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It does not provide registered devices list but its provide list of devices which un-registered means your app is uninstalled from device by using there feedback service.